NextJS and SocketIO with TypeScript, how to get the io server outside server.mjs
I setup a NextJS server written with TypeScript with a SocketIO communication as described on this page : https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-nextjs.
I have a "use server" file that I use for in that case upload files to the server with a server action. I would like to respond to that request with a broadcast message to all my clients with SocketIO, so with my io server.
My problem is that I don't know how to call io.emit() from my "use server" file, since io is a local variable in my server.mjs file.
Here are parts of my code:
// ./server.mjs

import { createServer } from "node:http";
import next from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = 3000;

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const httpServer = createServer(handler);

    const io = new Server(httpServer);

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log("Client connected");

        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            console.log("Client disconnected");
        });

        // Other socket connects here
    });

    httpServer
        .once("error", (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(1);
        })
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
        });
});

// ./app/fileManager

export async function uploadFile(data: FormData) {
    // Check validity and get dir path

    // For each file, if it is valid, upload it to the server
    const files: Array<File> = [];
    fileList.forEach((file) => {
        // Check file validity

        // Write file on the server
        file.arrayBuffer().then((bytes) => {
            const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);

            const filePath = path.join(fileDir, file.name);
            writeFile(filePath, buffer).then(() => {
                console.log(`${filePath} successfully uploaded to the server.`);
            });
        });

        // Add the new file to the list
        files.push(file);
    });

    // HERE, i want to send my files array to all of my clients instead of returning it.
    return files;
}

I mainly tried this:

Make io a global server.mjs variable and export it => not working, tries to execute server.mjs a second time.
Make io a global variable using a Singleton pattern in another file and import it in server.mjs => not working, got a Module not found error during server.mjs execution.

I have tried other variants of these two things, but none of these worked.
